# How can I get image from XMPP?

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework, avatar

I want to get user avatar image from XMPP, for this I do:

```
let photoData: NSData = (self.xmppvCardAvatarModule?.photoDataForJID(XMPPJID.jidWithString(onlineBuddies[indexPath.row] as! String)))!
cell.avatarImage.image = UIImage(data: photoData)
```

but it returns me the next error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

when I println this:

```
XMPPJID.jidWithString(onlineBuddies[indexPath.row] as! String)
```

it prints me username, but whole line returns me nil:

```
self.xmppvCardAvatarModule?.photoDataForJID(XMPPJID.jidWithString(onlineBuddies[indexPath.row] as! String))
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: you should fetch vcard ( sync or async ) if it  cant found from your db , it going to fetch from server , after receive vCard you can get it :)

Comment: @MohamadFarhand thanks for your response! Can you help me with it, please?

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to use like this :

```
[self.vCardTempModule fetchvCardTempForJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:phoneNumber] ignoreStorage:YES];
```

and handle photo in **Delegate**

```
- (void)xmppvCardTempModule:(XMPPvCardTempModule *)vCardTempModule
    didReceivevCardTemp:(XMPPvCardTemp *)vCardTemp
                 forJID:(XMPPJID *)jid
 {
    NSString * base64OfImage =  [[vCardTemp elementForName:@"PHOTO"]stringValue];
 }
```

also there is another way to receive the UIImage object from another Delegate , i recommend to see the documentation about vCard

```
-(void)xmppvCardAvatarModule:(XMPPvCardAvatarModule *)vCardTempModule didReceivePhoto:(UIImage *)photo forJID:(XMPPJID *)jid
```

Comment: it returns me an error `'Void' is not convertible to 'NSData'`. I converted your code to swift and got:

`let photoData: NSData = self.xmppvCardTempModule!.fetchvCardTempForJID(jIDis, ignoreStorage: true)
cell.avatarImage.image = UIImage(data: photoData)` there `let jIDis = XMPPJID.jidWithString(onlineBuddies[indexPath.row] as? String)` and in the app delegate `func xmppvCardTempModule(vCardTempModule: XMPPvCardTempModule, didReceivevCardTemp vCardTemp: XMPPvCardTemp, forJID jid: XMPPJID) {
        var base64OfImage: String = vCardTemp.elementForName("PHOTO").stringValue()
    }`

Comment: i think it's a void method & async , so you should receive Data in Delegates & after all , create nsdata :)

Comment: can you help me in chat, please?

Comment: mm ok bro, but i'm  a little busy @this time